# backpropagation for categorical cross entropy loss with sigmoid output layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement CNN(convolutional neural network) in C++. I have a sigmoid output layer.I would like to implement training with categorical cross entropy loss. I have found the equations for the same [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi8jNKa8c3uAhXBILcAHX8jAtUQFjACegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ics.uci.edu%2F%7Epjsadows%2Fnotes.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2H6wMbCuAZpdmnVoCNexaQ).
The equation for output delta for mean square error is : deltaj=(tj-oj)*(oj)*(1-oj)
the output delta for categorical cross entropy is: deltaj = (tj-oj)
where tj is the target value for output node j and oj is the actual value obtained on node j  in the forward pass.

For the hidden layers these output deltas are backpropagated and  there is no difference from mean square error loss function.

Please let me know if I am correct in my understanding the same?.

Comment: how many classes do you have? is it a single output for binary classification?

Comment: @Shai I have as many outputs as the no of classes .It is not a single output for binary classification.

Comment: If you are in a multi-class settings then sigmoid activation is not what you should use - you should use cross-entropy with _softmax_ and your calculations should vary accordingly.

Comment: I don't know why sigmoid is not to be used. The reference I have given has calculations for crossentropy in both cases sigmoid as well as softmax output layer.Also the equation for output units in both cases appears to be the same.

Comment: @Shai thanks for your reply. The reference I have given mentions logistic units.

Comment: @Shai  according to softmax the target values are probabilities. It is difficult to obtain data for the probability values.

Comment: This is the whole point of cross-entropy - you do not need probabilities for targets, just the class labels (it's {0,1} probability)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will need to look more at softmax function. I haven't probably not fully understood the same.